# Unique index corrupted SQL. Select query returns single row but create unique index fails

Tags: sql-server, index

I am not able to repair my database due to below errors, when I run `dbcc checkdb(DBNAME, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)` I am getting the errors listed here.

When I run a select query for these key values, it returns only one row, but when I run `dbcc checkdb(DBNAME, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)` these errors are thrown:

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' and the index
>   name 'uc1SycContents'. The duplicate key value is (7696031,
>   08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03).
>   Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' and the index
>   name 'nc2MSmerge_contents'. The duplicate key value is (424222,
>   7696031, 08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03).
>   Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' and the index
>   name 'nc4MSmerge_contents'. The duplicate key value is
>   (08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03, 7696031).
>   Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' and the index
>   name 'nc3MSmerge_contents'. The duplicate key value is (-425819,
>   7696031, bf8a5a9c-6f7d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03).
>   Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MSmerge_genhistory' with unique index 'unc1MSmerge_genhistory'.
>   Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_genhistory' and the
>   index name 'unc1MSmerge_genhistory'. The duplicate key value is
>   (236bfa48-965e-4a65-b4cd-ac527de04d1b, ).

How can I repair my database?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe you'll have to remove or change the records that contain the duplicated key value, otherwise I don't think it will be able to create the new index. Step 1: Backup the DB.

Comment: Not a programming question. Suggest this is moved to either DBA or ServerFault.

Comment: i am not able to find duplicate records :(

Comment: So none of those values that it lists in the error?

Comment: Why did you run DBCC with "REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS"? Restore from backup: if you have no backup, your data isn't important.

Comment: i cannot restore from backup because it is on subscriber database in merge replication. any other solution?

Comment: Show us the queries you run to find the duplicates

Comment: if you consider error,
Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' and the index name 'uc1SycContents'. The duplicate key value is (7696031, 08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03)......
I am running below Query
select * from msmerge_contents where rowguid='08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03' and it is returning only 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you consider error, Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The CREATE
>   UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found
>   for the object name 'dbo.MSmerge_contents' and the index name
>   'uc1SycContents'. The duplicate key value is (7696031,
>   08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03)...... I am running below Query
>      `select * from msmerge_contents where rowguid='08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03'`
>   and it is returning only 1 row

When you have index corruption problems (ie. keys present in NC index but not in base table or vice-versa) you must be very careful about the SQL you use to validate data. At this moment your data is inconsistent but the query optimizer does not know that and completely trusts your schema, including these incorrect indexes. As such it may optimize your query to use one of the NC indexes that is missing a key and the result will *also miss a a key* falsely returning no duplicates. To solve this catch-22 situation you need to force the optimizer hand by explicitly requesting an index or another *and* make sure the projected list of columns *can be satisfied by the index you enforced* (ie. no `*`). Assuming `uc1SycContents` is *not* the clustered index, try out the following:

```
select rowguid
from msmerge_contents with INDEX (1)
where rowguid='08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03';

select rowguid
from msmerge_contents with INDEX ([uc1SycContents])
where rowguid='08703987-557d-e111-9888-e61f13c44f03';
```

This will forcefully check if the rowguid has a duplicate for that guid in the base table clustered index (index id 1) vs. the index `uc1SycContents`. I expect that the first query returns 2 (or more) rows while the second returns 1.

Comment: i ran the queries you provided but it returned 1 row for both the queries. (i had to put paranthesis before and after index (INDEX (1))

Comment: Is `uc1SycContents` the clustered index?

Comment: Yes it is the clustered index

Comment: By the way i tried the same for table MSmerge_genhistory, and it gave me two rows after rebuilding indexes. same doesnt work for msmerge_contents

Comment: If `uc1SysContents` is the clustered index then the two queries above are basically the same. The important thing is to understand how you can force a specific index to query the data. Hopefully this will lead you to identifying the duplicates. You can try deactivating all indexes, remove the duplicate values, then enable back the indexes (will trigger a rebuild).

Comment: I disabled the indexes (including clustered index on MSMerge_contents), and then the query didnt run, then i rebuilded the indexes. After that when i ran DBCC CHECKDB (dbname, REPAIR_REBUILD) it only gave error for duplicate values MSmerge_genhistory table. I deleted the duplicate values and ran the DBCC again and all the errors were solved. Thanks a lot for your help, it wudn't have been possible without you :)

Comment: OK, you may experience some replication conflicts in the future because you have modified these tracking tables manually, but hopefully you will be able to resolve them.